# How to get the text value of a button from another layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

First of all, I have searched in forum for "**How to get text from edittext in other layout**", and tried many other ways, then I decided to use **LayoutInflater** but it did not help.

The implementation of LayoutInflater (I follow this guide)

```
LayoutInflater factory = getLayoutInflater();
View regisText = factory.inflate(R.layout.regis, null);
EditText user = (EditText) regisText.findViewById(R.id.edt1); 
String usr = user.getText().toString();
```

My parent layout is named **activity_input.xml** having 3 buttons (I do not set text button). I put only **button Id** for easy view.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1">
</Button>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn2">
</Button>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn3">
</Button>
```

After I click a button, one dialog appears to select value (1, 2 or 3) to **set the button display text (1, 2 or 3)** in **activity_input.xml**.

```
final Dialog dialog1 = new Dialog(user_input.this);
            dialog1.setTitle("Select a Number");
            dialog1.setContentView(R.layout.game_dialog);
            dialog1.show();

            button1 = (Button) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
            button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Button p1_btn = (Button) findViewById(x);
                    p1_btn.setText("1");
                    dialog1.dismiss();
                }
            });
```

The **onClick** works perfect.

But my problem is that I want to **get the text of the button in parent layout** again, I try to implement Layoutinflater but it does not work, here is the code.

```
LayoutInflater f1 = getLayoutInflater();
    View v1 = f1.inflate(R.layout.activity_input, null);
    Button btn1 = (Button) v1.findViewById(R.id.b1);
    String t1 = btn1.getText().toString();
```

I check to make sure that the **String t1** is retrieve successfully by print the string but it shows nothing

Hope you guide help me as soon as possible!

Thanks you very much.

Comment: You can make a `static` variable and store the result there, then access it from your `dialog`

Comment: Can you make it more clear? Where to declare a static variable in that function?

Comment: Where do you get the button text in the parent layout? Maybe the text isnt set yet when you try to access it

Comment: I can make sure that After the diablog calling, Ithe button text in the parent layout is set successfully, and it display immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `static` variable and store the result there, then access it from your dialog. So in your **ActivityInput.java**

```
public class ActivityInput extends Activity {

    public static String input = "";

    //code

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Button p1_btn = (Button) findViewById(x);
            input = "1";
            p1_btn.setText(input);
            dialog1.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

Now in your other java class **ActivityOutput.java**:

```
public class ActivityOutput extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //code
        String result = ActivityInput.input;
        //use the result string somewhere to display it in your app
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you help! I'm trying now.